# A word or sentence that makes no sense until you understand the irregular spelling

Tags: phrase-requests, pronunciation-vs-spelling, pronunciation-respelling

English has a "intricate" relationship between graphemes and phonemes,i.e. there is no sure way of knowing how to pronounce something by just looking at its written form.

Generally any language has this property, but English is much more complicated in comparison to - say - Italian (which happens to be my native language).

This fact is known, and I remember stumbling upon a very nice sentence by an English Author, who leverage on this fact and wrote a sentence whose words did not make any sense together, but if you read them, then the "sounds" formed a perfectly meaningful phrase.

I seem to remember something concerning "god" and a "fish"?

Not sure though.

Anybody remember that?

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of the story of [Ladle Rat Rotten Hut](http://www.exploratorium.edu/exhibits/ladle/)?

Comment: @Helion -- Well, I am not so sure, that was quite some time ago and the general topic was the intricate relationship between written and spoken form which is there in English or French, far less in German or Italian.
I remember something between the two extremes of a single word and a full story :-)
What you linked however made my point, and it is really interesting.
Thanks for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ghoti**

> **Ghoti** is a creative respelling of the word **fish**, used to illustrate irregularities in English spelling. ...
>
> Explanation
>
> The word is intended to be pronounced in the same way (/ˈfɪʃ/), using
>   these sounds:
>
> gh, pronounced [f] as in tough [tʌf];
>
> o, pronounced [ɪ] as in women [ˈwɪmɪn];
>
> and ti, pronounced [ʃ] as in nation [ˈneɪʃən].
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghoti

As far as I know, there was never a complete sentence base on 'ghoti'.

I'm not aware of a name for the phenomenon.

Comment: Also look at http://q-pheevr.livejournal.com/2897.html for the way to read Psschaughal.

Comment: I also have never seen a complete sentence based on it, however, I have seen a longer, more amusing example: "ghoughpteighbteau" (pronounced "potato"). Also fun fact I learned about 3 seconds ago: presumably in reference to this, the word for "fish" in Klingon is apparently "ghoti".

Comment: @neminem: Ah, you speak Welsh :-)